# как прописать путь к статическому фото в админке,

Tags: wordpress

в админке в контакт форм 7 я вставил свою форму, но у меня есть там статическое фото, которое должно тянуться с папки Img, если в php файле то все такие фото я выводил так `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/photo.png">` в контакт форм 7 я тоже перенес форму и фото с этим кодом, но ничего не выводит, как правильно нужно прописать путь к файлу?

Comment: А что мешает прямо указать адрес картинки? И вооще делать такое через `bloginfo` моветон. Тем более из темы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код php не будет исполняться в форме.

Вам надо указать относительный путь до папки, примерно так:

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/img/photo.png">
```